# Shell script do timed task stop and repeat?

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

I am working with programs that use CTRL-C to stop a task, and what I want to do is to run that task for certain number of minutes and then have it stop like CTRL-C was pressed. The reason why I want it to stop like ctrl+c was pressed is because it auto saves when you stop the program instead of killing it and possibly losing the saved data.

edit; I don't want to use cron unless if it stops my script it will have the program save the data, I am hoping to accomplish this inside the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

The trap statement catches these sequences and can be programmed to execute a list of commands upon catching those signals.

-#!/bin/bash

trap "echo Saving Data" SIGINT

while :
do
        sleep 60
done

For Information on Traps : http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html

Comment: I still don't understand seems trap only works if I hit ctrl+c? what I wanted to do is do a task for certain amount of time like, lets say, for 2 minutes, and then I want it to automatically stop the task as if someone hit ctrl + c then loop back and do the task again for another two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Using [timeout command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) to send `SIGINT` after 60 seconds:

```
timeout --signal=INT 60 /path/to/script.sh params
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to intercept <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, you should use the `trap` builtin, like this :

```
cleanup(){ # do something...; }

trap 'cleanup' 2

# rest of the code
```

`2` on `trap` line is the `SIGINT` signal sended by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, see `man 7 signals`

Comment: whats the 2 after trap clean up mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
/path/to/script.sh params &
set +m

bg_pid=$!

sleep 60

kill -2 $bg_pid
```

This should allow you to send `SIGINT` to a backgrounded process using [Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) and the [set builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)